# How can I fix a password that ends with a hash

Tags: coldfusion, directory, passwords

In ColdFusion, my password ends with a hash symbol `#`. So whenever I try to use this value to connect, it won't accept my password. I tried to use 3 hashes but still the error exists.

```
     name="directoryWatcher"
     server="localhost"
     username="******"
     password="********#"
```

Comment: Use `##` to escape `#`

Comment: *i tried to use 3 hashes*  Just to be crystal clear - in CF use 2 hashes to generate a literal `#`, not 3.

Comment: Can you post some of the context for where this is? Is it cfscript or tags? Within an output or just a cfm/function?

Answer (score 1):

As per CF code work flow, the ## also consider as # with in cfoutput . So you should pass one more # with your password( As per seybsen comment). Like below code

```
<cfset password = "*****##"> Here add one # with your password. 

name="directoryWatcher"
server="localhost"
username="******"
password="#password#"
```

Imagine if your password like `<cfset password = "123#" >` means then you can add one more # like `<cfset password = "123##">` While assign these variable value in password attributes the CF consider ## as # with in cfoutput. So the result of `password="#password#"` -- > `password = "123#".`

Answer (score 0):

As Seybsen says you can escape the hash with a hash, so # becomes ##; alternatively you could set the password as a variable.

`<cfset password = "********#">`

`name="directoryWatcher"
server="localhost"
username="******"
password="#password#"`

Comment: No.It's should return the error. Please check well. if you are set password = '*****#' and passed the values in password attributes it's consider as password="#*****##". So it's should return the error.

Comment: Not if it's set as a variable, there's some differences with script vs tags but generally using a variable will allow this to work.